Tables in article do not fit when moving to report (documentclass)
I would like to know if there is an alternative solution to the package \usepackage{pdfpages}.
I have three papers written in \documentclass{article}. When I compile each paper individually, there is no problem. Now, I want to put them all together for my thesis in a \documentclass{report}. I'm open to other documentclasses if they are better solutions.
My problem is that when I put all together in the thesis, the tables from the the papers (articles) do not fit anymore in the page. I like the {report} because of how it manages TOCs. At the moment all the papers have their own preamble but it seems it doesn't matter when they are called in the thesis as the tables do not fit anymore.
Even if I have the same packages in the thesis main.tex as in each articles. The tables still do not fit.
This is how my thesis looks:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
...other packages for referencing, mathformatting, etc (all same packages in articles are use here to avoid missing any)

\begin{document}

\subfile{Cover_Files/Cover_Pages.tex}

% % ******* Adding TOC and List of Figures *******

\thispagestyle{empty}
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{title}
\subfile{Cover_Files/Introduction.tex}

\newpage
\chapter{Paper 01 Name}
\subfile{p_01/p_01.tex}

\end{document}

This is the table used in the article, when compiled it fits the page with no issues. When compile in report it doesn't fit anymore.
\begin{table}[htbp]
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\label{LABEL}CAPTION}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{l}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{TEXT}} \\
 Model:           & (1)           & (2)       & (3) \\
            & 2010-2021     & 2010-2015 & 2016-2021 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{A. TEXT}}\\
\addlinespace
\emph{Variables}\\
A      & 1111111$ & 1111111  & 1111111 \\
           & 1111111     & 1111111    & 1111111     \\
M     & 1111111 & 1111111 & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111      & 1111111    & 1111111      \\
H        & 1111111       & 1111111   & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111      & 1111111    & 1111111      \\
S        & 1111111  & 1111111 & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111     & 1111111     & 1111111      \\
U        & 1111111        & 1111111      & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111      & 1111111     & 1111111      \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\emph{Fit statistics}\\
Observations   & 1       & 1       & 1        \\
R$^2$        & $0.080$       & $0.138$       & $0.063$       \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{B. TEXT}}\\
Model:          & (1)           & (2)       & (3) \\
            & 2010-2021     & 2010-2015 & 2016-2021 \\
\hline
\emph{Variables}\\
A      & 1111111$ & 1111111  & 1111111 \\
           & 1111111     & 1111111    & 1111111     \\
M     & 1111111 & 1111111 & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111      & 1111111    & 1111111      \\
H        & 1111111       & 1111111   & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111      & 1111111    & 1111111      \\
S        & 1111111  & 1111111 & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111     & 1111111     & 1111111      \\
U        & 1111111        & 1111111      & 1111111  \\
           & 1111111      & 1111111     & 1111111      \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\emph{Fit statistics}\\
Observations   & 1        & 1        & 1        \\
R$^2$      & $0.041$        & $0.129$       & $0.036$        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\scriptsize \par \justify
\textbf{Note: }A lot of text, enough text that does not fit      
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

Edit: added the table as MWE.

report and article use the same defaults for font size and text width. So without knowing the details of your documents and without minimal working example, that would allow us to reproduce your problem, it is hard to answer your question. I would guess, that your article documents use either explicitly another font size or another page layout. But there are a lot of other things, that can cause your issue.

Don't use external files. I would suggest to edit your question. Copy a problematic content from the three articles into the thesis file (report) with sample texts (no external files). Post the code here and make sure: the code is self-contained and ready to compile; it's minimal to only reproduce the issues; you have described the difference between what you get and what you expect. Don't hesitate to post a screenshot of a PDF.

Thanks for both replies. I will try to make the MWE better and share it again or post a new question. I am sort of new with this. Apologies

Your table can't compile as there are spurious $ signs in it.
